# How do I use Git on my C#.NET azure website for user content updates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, user-input, azure-web-app-service

### Motivation

We are developing an Azure website in C# ASP.NET MVC and we want to improve cooperation with our clients/admin users who optionally co-develop "content" of the website with us.

The application generates different outputs based on user defined "parameters" (plain data stored in SQL Database) interpreted trough user defined "fcs templates" ("application specific script source files" currently stored in blob storage).

We manage the C# code in a private repository (GitHub) and regularly deploy the binaries from Visual Studio via web deployment process. This works great.

We manage the "fcs templates" on another GitHub repository which is accessible also by the client and we upload them on demand of us/admin-user to blob storage, where they can be accessed from the application (cached locally in memory and maybe later in local cache/disk).

Later on, we would like to have the application checkout and use the "fcs templates" directly from GitHub as smartly as possible and based on the user web request. Possibly even to have "more working directories" to sandbox development branch separate from the master branch of the "fcs templates", so that users can test the impact of their change before they confirm it for other users of the application.

I know that thanks to Kudu, there is git installed on the VM hosting my website, and I may take the risk and try to somehow "shell git" create some working directory in "D:\home\site\wwwroot\my_fcs_branches_mess", but I want to stick as much as possible to the Microsoft "game rules" for c#.NET web app development and deployment and avoid too much of undocumented hacks. Still, I am willing to take a little risk, though, if it will look promising based on your feedback.

I want to stress out, that I am not asking for automated git deployment of the C# application, which surely is possible with kudu. I do not want the user to deploy the whole application, but only update a small subset of the user content.

### The actual question

Is there a way to take advantage of git on the actual VM where my standard azure website is deployed so that our application can use for the client modifying the client content "fcs templates"?

Does someone use Git to manage not only the actual source code but also the user content of the website? How?

Comment: To be honest with you, you may want to look at the GitHub APIs. It maybe possible to do everything you want through them. If not, there are a fair few C# libraries that do `git`, otherwise, yeah you can use `Process` in C# to kick off the shell Git. Fortunately `Process` allows you to pipe the out back through into your app, so you can let people know the status

Comment: You could use a virtual machine instead of an app service, and have background process running that do your git stuff. Or as I like to do, have some WebApi2 web services on the VM communicate data from the app service and the VM processes. You do need to be aware of the limitations of executing `exe`s from the app service.... hence why i have an internal vm

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I am also considering Octokit library to download content of branch directly to my process. Nevertheless, I thought anyway about caching the downloaded branch to local storage, so I would be duplicating git client functionality anyway. So 'Process' still sounds viable.

Comment: You are right, but regarding the VM, I do not want to leave the comfort of web site development and abstracting from the actual VM for most of the scenarios. This scenario is not for me "the one" which would advocate such a shift.

Comment: You wouldn't be leaving the "comfort" of web dev. You have to consider that an app service won't allow you execute exes. VM gives you more security because you can restrict the calls going in, so if someone compromises your app service, your VM isn't compromised. A VM will give you more control over the Git part, but I'm not advocating moving away from your app service.

Comment: I think this question is far too broad and likely not a good fit for SO. Please see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). *"Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."*

Comment: Ok. I will try to ask better next time. Nevertheless, the answer of Callum Linington is sufficient for me as it clearly helped me to realize that if I decide for execution of 'exe' I should move to VM.